# Is there a way to add clauses like accept = 'image/*' to input items via forms API?

Tags: forms

I'd like to add "accept" attributes to some of the input fields for my site's content types -- to end up with something like `<input type="file" id="edit-field-whatever-und-0-upload" name="files[field_whatever_und_0]" size="22" class="form-file" accept="image/*">`, so that (most) browsers will limit the selectable items to .jpg, .png, etc.  I've tried doing this by adding an `#attributes` clause to a form's `hook_form_alter` handler, but haven't been able to find the right way to write the clause -- I can't get the `accept` clause to show up in the html.

In place of this, I'm currently adding it through some jQuery that runs on document.ready, but it would feel cleaner if I could do it through the forms api. Is this possible? Any hints out there?  Thanks!

Comment: There is now a module that does this: [File Accept](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_accept)

Answer (score 2):

You can override theme_file to achieve above if you would like to alter file input element in template.php ..

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_file($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'file';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-file'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' accept="image/*" />';
}
```

below code works for me

```
function seven_file($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'file';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-file'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' accept="image/*" />';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting/thanks, but I think it's not general enough -- some fields need to be restricted to image/*, while others (sometimes in the same content type) need to be restricted to video/*.  But it looks like you're confirming (so far) that there's no clear way to do it with an `#attributes` clause...

Answer (score 0):

Old question but i wanted to solve this same issue and this led me to come up with a general solution to set the accept attribute for all drupal file and image widgets.

```
/**
* Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
*/
function MODULENAME_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context)
{
  switch ($context['field']['type'])
  {
    case 'file':
    case 'image':
    {
      // add custom file widget process callback
      $element[$context['delta']]['#process'][] = '_MODULENAME_file_process';
      break;
    }
  }
}

/**
* Custom element process callback for file widgets
**/
function _MODULENAME_file_process($element, &$form_state, $form)
{
  // set accept attribute from allowed extensions
  $exts_string = @$element['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][0];
  if ($exts_string)
  {
    $exts = explode(' ', $exts_string);
    $element['upload']['#attributes']['accept'] = '.' . implode(', .', $exts);
  }

  return $element;
}
```